# Can I get a closed form solution of this SDP?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & \mathbf{A} -t \mathbf{B} \succeq 0\end{array}$$

where $\mathbf{A}\succeq0$ and $\mathbf{B}\succeq0$. I want to ask one question. Can I get $t$ in closed form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the smallest generalized eigenvalue of the pair $(A,B)$. In MATLAB, you would compute it as `min(eig(A,B))`

Comment: can i get a reference paper or link(or keyword to find about that)???

Comment: Well, generalized eigenvalue problem is a classical problem, hence that is the keyword...

Comment: @user405592 Take a look at section 2.2.3 in [Linear Matrix Inequalities in System and Control Theory](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/lmibook/).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you!!